# A question about the use of parenthesis with arguments

Tags: python, parentheses, brackets

```
def calculate_pythagoras():
    pythagoras_list = list()
    for i in range(1, 101):
        for j in range(1, 101):
            c = (i ** 2 + j ** 2) ** 0.5
            if (c == int(c)):
                pythagoras_list.append((i, j, int(c)))
    return pythagoras_list


for i in calculate_pythagoras():
    print(i)

    pythagoras_list.append((i, j, int(c)))
```

Correct:

```
((i, j, int(c)))
```

Incorrect:

```
(i, j, int(c))
```

Why do I get an error when I remove the outer parenthesis?

Comment: In this case, it's the difference between appending a tuple and trying to call append with three positional arguments. You didn't include it in the post, but the error tells you: `TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def calculate_pythagoras():
    pythagoras_list=list()
    for i in range(1,101):
        for j in range(1,101):
            c=(i**2 + j**2)**0.5
            if(c==int(c)):
                pythagoras_list.append((i,j,int(c))) # You're calling the append method with those extra parentheses.
    return pythagoras_list

for i in calculate_pythagoras():
    print(i)


"""

pythagoras_list.append((i,j,int(c)))


((i,j,int(c)))----->correct

(i,j,int(c))----->incorrect

why do i get an error when i remove the outer parenthesis?

*** calls append( (set of items ( int ) ) )

"""
```